# Select all html select elements inside frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following structure of the html document:

```
<frameset cols="25%,50%,25%">
    <frame name="name1" src="frame_a.htm">
    <frame name="name2" src="frame_b.htm">
</frameset>
```

Both frame_a.htm and frame_b.htm return a form with select elments:

```
<form>
    <select id="select1">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <select id="select4">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

and

```
<form>
    <select id="select2">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

How to select all selector elements of the first frame only?

I've tried the following options:

```
jQuery("frame[name='name1'] select").each(function( index ) {
     var elementID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
     alert(elementID);
});
jQuery("frame[name='name1']").find('select').each(function( index ) {
     var elementID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
     alert(elementID);
});
jQuery("frame[name='name1']").contents().find('select').each(function( index ) {
     var elementID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
     alert(elementID);
});
```

But it did not help.
Also, I try to alert frame, it worked:

```
    jQuery("frame[name='name1']").each(function( index ) {
        alert("test1");
    } );
```

But when try to alert all select elements, it doesn't:

```
    jQuery( "select" ).each(function( index ) {
        alert("test2");
    });
```

Note: I'm loading code using:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        //here I put JavaScript code
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've found, please correct me if I'm wrong.

First, I put code into the  element of the main html document. It looked like:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       // put JavaScript code here
    </script>
</head>
<frameset cols="25%,50%">
    <frame name="name1" src="frame_a.htm">
    <frame name="name2" src="frame_b.htm">
</frameset>
```

And it did not help. Even the following did not help (frames in the second case are loaded):

```
jQuery("frame[name='name1']").load( function() { ...}
```

Second. I had to move all JavaScript code into the child html files. In my case they are `frame_a.htm` and `frame_b.htm`. And each file has the following JavaScript code now:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    for( var i = 0; i < parent.frames.length; ++i )
    {
        if( parent.frames[i].name == "name2" && self === parent.frames[i])
        {
            jQuery("select").each(function( index ) {
                var elementID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
                alert( elementID );
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Probably there is another more effective solution, but this one has resolved my problem. Frames - are evil, try don't use them:)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery("frame[name='name1']").contents().find('select').each(function( index ) {
     var elementID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
     alert(elementID);
});
```

Comment: Your options does not work for me:( Cannot understand why. The following does alert: jQuery("frame[name='name1']").each(function( index ) {
 alert("test1");  } );
But when I try to alert for each select element it does not work:
 jQuery( "select" ).each(function( index ) {
  alert("test2");
 });
Need help:)

Comment: @Alexandr because the `select` element are not in the current document root there are in different document

Comment: I see. Then, how to find out why your original option does not help? Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
$("frame[name='name1']").contents().find("select")
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
#("frame[name='name1']).contents().find("select").each(function( index ) {
 var elementID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
 alert(elementID);
});
#("frame[name='name1']").find('select').contents().find("select").each(function( index ) {
 var elementID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
 alert(elementID);
});
```